# Change javascript array value of 0 to null value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a few arrays that are laid out like so:

```
var row1 = [4,6,4,0,9];
var row2 = [5,2,0,8,1];
var row3 = [2,0,3,1,6];
```

I want to replace any values that have 0 with a null value. so they would look like:

```
var row1 = [4,6,4,,9];
var row2 = [5,2,,8,1];
var row3 = [2,,3,1,6];
```

Any ideas? Basically what I'm trying to do is loop through each value of the array, check to see if it equals 0, and if so replace it with a null value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What part are you stuck at? Your description would just work.

Comment: You may also be interested in https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: `[4,6,4,,9]` isn't valid. Did you mean `[4,6,4,null,9]`? I.E. maintain the `.length` property? Or did you want the 0s removed, leaving you with `[4,6,4,9]`?

Comment: @CrescentFresh: It's valid. It just puts a hole in the Array. Given your example... `3 in array; // false`

Comment: @squint: neat. `.forEach` skips element `3` too (whereas something like jQuery.each() does not). OP: are holes acceptable then? Answering it means the different between `delete a[index]` and `a[index] = null`, two semantically different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var row1 = [4,6,4,0,9];
var row2 = [5,2,0,8,1];
var row3 = [2,0,3,1,6];

var arrRows = [row1, row2, row3];

for (var i = 0; i < arrRows.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arrRows[i].length; j++) {
        if (arrRows[i][j] == 0) {
            arrRows[i][j] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/npYr2/

Comment: `arrRows[i][j] == 0` will return `true` also on `null`, `undefined`, `""`, and `NaN`. if You want only to convert 0 to tull you should use `===`

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
row1 = row1.map(function(val, i) {
    return val === 0 ? null : val;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Mz38/

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is the following

```
var rows = [row1, row2, row3];

rows = rows.map(function(x){ return x.map(function(y){ return y === 0? null: y})});
```